# How to setup to auto connect to wireless through command line without storing password in plaintext?

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, wifi-configuration

The system I am running is Ubuntu mate on a Rasp Pi 3. 
I have it set up where I ssh in through the Ethernet connection. I want to now set it up to auto connect to my home WIFI network on boot. The router is currently using WPA2-PSK [AES] for encryption/login.
From everything I have been able to find, [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-wpa-wpa2-wireless-wifi-networking/) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294257/connect-to-wifi-network-through-ubuntu-terminal), they suggest methods that would leave my WIFI password/passphrase in plaintext or have the connect be manual on each boot.

Does anyone know a method where I can set this up but the password is encrypted? 
Yes, I know I could just turn the GUI back on and connect the monitor but it is not about that. It should be possible to set it up through terminal without having the password be in plaintext.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you propose that this encrypted password be decrypted? With a key stored on the device? Suddenly, you're no more secure than plaintext... at best, it's a very thin layer of obfuscation.

Comment: You have two choices here, really: store a plaintext password, or prompt a user to enter a password every time. Which would not be automatic. Personally, I would not worry overly much about the wireless AP password, since anyone who has access do the Pi in that manner has access to the AP anyway.